# Возможно ли получить доступ к закрытым членам внутреннего класса?

Tags: c++, классы, inner

Начало класса:

```
template<class T>
class List : public Collection<T> {
private:
    class Node {
    private:
        Node* _next;
        Node* _prev;

    public:
        T _data;
    };
```

Первая ошибка доступа:

```
~List() {
    while (_head) {
        _tail = _head->_next; //я не вижу _next!!!
        delete _head;
        _head = _tail;
    }
}
```

Не хотелось бы оставлять next и prev открытыми из очевидных предположений. Можно что-то изменить?

Comment: а какие "очевидные причины"? ООП? Ну тогда сделайте себе getter/setter/

Comment: Например, объявите внешний класс другом внутреннего...

Comment: Приведите больше кода. А именно - проиллюстрируйте свои "очевидные причины". Я думаю, что понимаю, о чем вы говорите. Но проблему лишнего доступа, возможно, можно решить и другими методами.

Comment: @AnT Как писал в комментарии к ответу ниже, я одержим принципами "безопасности", в смысле максимального сокрытия членов класса. Но, выходит, они действительно преувеличены в моём понимании

Comment: @xt1zer: Почему вы решили, что они преувеличены? Приведенные ранее ответы лишь вводили в заблуждение. Не надо так быстро верить всему, что вы тут читаете. Ваши опасения совсем не преувеличены, но должны ли они иметь место в вашем конкретном случае - зависит от деталей и намерений, которые вы тут не описали.

Answer (score 0):

Есть разные варианты, например, сделать класс другом или добавить в него открытые функции доступа к полям.

В своем стремлении все закрыть вы сделали "вещь в себе" - класс, в котором есть только закрытые члены, к которым может обращаться только сам класс. Но если к ним может обращаться только класс, то логично попросить его об этом? Т.е. добавить функции-члены для работы с закрытыми членами-данными, нет?

Иначе зачем вам этот чемодан, закрытый на ключ, который находится в чемодане? :)

Comment: Но есть же какие-то принципы "безопасности" в отношении спецификаторов класса? Скажем, зачем пользователю знать об указателях next и prev? Их изменение может порвать весь список напрочь

Comment: "Пользователь" - это кто? Это только вы сами, в лице класса `List` :) Простите уж, но любая безопасность не должна становиться самоцелью - иначе будет как в том анекдоте, когда мужик, боясь заразиться, простите уж, одевал три презерватива, а для пущей безопасности даже при этом избегал женщин... О безопасности - почитайте на досуге Саттера, "Сложные задачи" (или "Новые.." - точно не помню), как легко обходятся все эти `private`... Да и вам надо только прочесть значение поля - ну так `Node* next() const { return next_; }` не даст никому изменить поле, зато даст его прочесть, не рвя список...

Comment: Предположение о том, что пользователем закрытого внутреннего класса может являться только внешний класс - неверно. Приватность внутреннего класса закрывает внешним пользователям доступ к вложенному имени `Node` - но не более того. Достаточно внешнему пользователю как-то получить указатель на `Node` (из какого-то метода `List`, например) и пользователь получит доступ ко всем открытым членам `Node`. Видимо, этим и руководствуется автор вопроса. Так что никакого "чемодан, закрытый на ключ, который находится в чемодане" тут нет.

Comment: @AnT С тем же успехом можно объявить рядом такую же структуру, выполнить приведение и работать. Можно и еще другими способами (я упомянул Саттера, у него этому посвящена отдельная задача). Но это все - хак. А что касается чемодана - то я пытался показать, что ТС закрыл доступ сам от себя в первую очередь.

Comment: Ну это совершенно несравнимые вещи. Я говорю не о хаках. Я говорю о невинном `auto *p = list.detach_node();`. Если метод `detach_node` возвращает `List::Node *`, то теперь мы имеем полный доступ к публичным членам `List::Node`: выражение `p->next` является валидным если `List::Node::next` публичен. То есть мы может делать все, что угодно, пока нам не надо упоминать вслух `List::Node`. К имени `List::Node` у нас доступа нет, но `auto` позволяет нам прекрасно обойтись без него. Никаких "хаков" тут нет даже отдаленно.

Comment: @AnT То, о чем рассказываете вы - это **преднамеренное** открытие внутренностей наружу. С тем же успехом можно просто написать везде `struct` и `public` (и использовать `gets`:) )

Comment: @Harry: Это уже вопрос к автору вопроса. Вполне возможно, что как раз в этом и состоит задача: преднамеренно разрешить использование `List::Node *` снаружи, но при этом не дать внешнему пользователю доступа к `List::Node::next`. Я нередко встречаю именно такой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно стандарту C++ (14.7 Nested classes):

> 1 A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as
>   any other member. **The members of an enclosing class have no special
>   access to members of a nested class;** the usual access rules (Clause
>   14) shall be obeyed.

То есть члены внешнего класса не имеют специальных прав доступа к членам вложенного класса.

Вы могли бы класс `List` объявить дружественным к вложенному классу `Node`.

Так как у вас класс `Node` вложенный и определен как private-член внешнего класса, то нет никакой необходимости объявлять еще его члены как private.

Comment: "... то нет никакой необходимости объявлять еще его члены как private." - это почему это? Предположение о том, что пользователем закрытого внутреннего класса может являться только внешний класс - неверно. Приватность внутреннего класса закрывает внешним пользователям доступ к вложенному имени `Node` - но не более того. Достаточно внешнему пользователю как-то получить указатель на `Node` (из какого-то метода `List`, например) и пользователь получит доступ ко всем открытым членам `Node`. Скорее всего именно это и пытается предотвратить автор вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не описываете этого в своем вопросе, но проблемы с нежелательным доступом к членам такого класса вполне возможны во вполне естественных ситуациях. Например, если ваш класс `List` предоставляет методы для работы с подсписками или узлами связного списка, т.е. методы вроде `splice`, `detach` и т.п. Например в таком коде

```
class List
{
   class Node 
   {
   public:
     Node *next;
     ...
   };

 public:
   Node *detach_first();
};
```

пользователь такого класса `List` будет иметь возможность сделать

```
int main()
{
  List list;
  ...
  auto *p = list.deatch_first();
  // `p->next` - свободно доступен здесь
}
```

и после этого получить свободный доступ к публичным полям класса `List::Node`. Более того, пользователь может сделать

```
using ListNode = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(list.deatch_first())>;
```

и вот уже у вас в руках есть сам закрытый тип `list::Node`, без применения каких-либо "хаков".

Помещение класса `List::Node` в приватный раздел класса `List` лишает внешних пользователей лишь возможности впрямую упоминать имя `List::Node` во внешнем коде, но не более того. Вышеприведенный код, например, использует `auto` и обходится без упоминания имени `List::Node`, получая при этом совершенно законный доступ ко всему интерфейсу `List::Node`. То есть никакой ситуации "закрытого чемодана в закрытом чемодане" тут нет. Вам лишь запрещено называть внутренний чемодан "чемоданом". (Все это, кстати, реализуемо и в С++98, без `auto` и `decltype`, хоть там это и требует дополнительных телодвижений.)

Тот факт, что защита, предоставляемая таким закрытым объявлением вложенного класса, настолько "тонка" и узконаправленна, зачастую является сюрпризом даже для подготовленных С++ программистов.

Однако, возвращаясь к исходной задаче (в моем ее понимании):

1. Если ваш класс `List`, согласно вашему замыслу, действительно должен давать внешним пользователям доступ к значениям типа `List::Node`, то имеет смысл все таки сделать `List::Node` открытым (public) членом `List` - скрывать его никакого смысла нет.

   Если вы хотите при этом запретить доступ к реализации `List::Node`, то следует сделать все члены `List::Node` закрытыми (private), а класс `List` сделать другом класса `List::Node`.
2. Но лучше все таки пойти по другому пути: оставить класс `List::Node` закрытым в `List` и сделать все члены `List::Node` открытыми. Последнее позволит `List` доступаться к членам `List::Node`. Но при этом надо позаботиться о том, чтобы внешний пользователь *никогда* не получал прямого доступа к значениям типа `List::Node`. Все внешние методы, вроде `detach_fist`, `splice` и т.д. должны работать не через `List::Node *`, а через публичный `List::NodeHandle` - некий opaque тип, который прячет внутри себя значение `List::Node *`, но не открывает этого факта внешнему пользователю. То есть в данном случае мы предпринимаем дополнительные усилия для того, чтобы "закрытый чемодан" действительно был закрытым.

   Например, простейшим вариантом такого `List::NodeHandle` будет просто `void *`. Внутри методов `List` вы просто будете приводить его к `List::Node *`. В тривиальных контейнерах в качестве `List::NodeHandle` может выступать их итератор. В более сложных может понадобится отдельная абстракция. Обратите внимание, что начиная с С++17 стандартная библиотека С++ поддерживает подобный интерфейс для классов стандартных ассоциативных контейнеров, основанный именно на "node handle" подходе: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle